# How to hide edit template when there is no data

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I am using a `grid view` in which i am giving two options,

1. If u have data in database, it will show in `edit template`,
2. If there is no data `footer template` will b displayed for `entering new data`.

   But when i try 2nd point,Blank edit template also gets displayed above Footer Row with Edit button please suggest me how to hide that edit template when there is no data.

My code is

design:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvNavigationDtls" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SkinID="GridView"
                                        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="gridAltRow" RowStyle-CssClass="gridRow" ShowFooter="True"
                                        EditRowStyle-CssClass="gridEditRow" FooterStyle-CssClass="gridFooterRow">
                                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridAltRow" />
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OBSERVATION CODE" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                                                ControlStyle-Width="150px">
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("code_name") %>' Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCode" runat="server" Height="20px" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle"
                                                        ImageUrl="~/Images/openFolder.png" OnClientClick="ShowSearch('Code',this); return false;"
                                                        TabIndex="5" Width="20px" />
                                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCodeCd" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("NAV_DEF_CODE_CD") %>' />
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCode" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCode" runat="server" Height="20px" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle"
                                                        ImageUrl="~/Images/openFolder.png" OnClientClick="ShowSearch('Code',this); return false;"
                                                        TabIndex="5" Width="20px" />
                                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCodeCd" runat="server" />
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <%--<asp:Label ID="lblCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("code_name") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
                                                    <%# Eval("code_name")%>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <ControlStyle Width="150px" />
                                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DESCRIPTION" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ControlStyle-Width="150px">
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OBSERVATION") %>'
                                                        Width="150px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Width="150px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <%# Eval("OBSERVATION")%>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <ControlStyle Width="150px" />
                                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="STATUS" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ControlStyle-Width="80px">
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OBS_STATUS") %>' Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStatus" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <%# Eval("OBS_STATUS")%>
                                                    <%--      <%# Eval("NAV_OBS_DTL_CD")%>--%>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <ControlStyle Width="80px" />
                                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ShowHeader="False" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                                                        Text="Update" OnClientClick="return confirm('Update?')" ValidationGroup="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vsUpdate" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false"
                                                        ValidationGroup="Update" Enabled="true" HeaderText="Validation Summary..." />
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                                                        Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnNavObsDtlCd" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("NAV_OBS_DTL_CD") %>' />
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAdd" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert"
                                                        ValidationGroup="Insert" Text="Insert"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vsInsert" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false"
                                                        ValidationGroup="Insert" Enabled="true" HeaderText="Validation..." />
                                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnNavObsDtlCd" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("NAV_OBS_DTL_CD") %>' />
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                                                        Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFlag" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("Flag") %>' />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
                                        <EditRowStyle CssClass="gridEditRow" />
                                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                            <table class="grid" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="gvNavigationDtls"
                                                style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th align="left" scope="col">
                                                        Observation Code
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th align="left" scope="col">
                                                        Description(initial comm.)
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th align="left" scope="col">
                                                        Status
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th align="left" scope="col">
                                                    </th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr class="gridRow">
                                                    <td colspan="8">
                                                        No Records found...
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr class="gridFooterRow">
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCode" runat="server" MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStatus" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td colspan="2" align="justify" valign="middle">
                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAdd" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="emptyInsert"
                                                            Text="emptyInsert"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                        <FooterStyle CssClass="gridFooterRow" />
                                        <RowStyle CssClass="gridRow" />
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

Function for adding Empty row in footer:

```
 private void ShowNoResultFound(DataTable source, GridView gv)
    {
 source.Columns.Add("code_name");
        source.Columns.Add("OBSERVATION");
        source.Columns.Add("OBS_STATUS");
        source.Columns.Add("Flag");
        source.Rows.Add(source.NewRow()); // create a new blank row to the DataTable
        // Bind the DataTable which contain a blank row to the GridView
        gv.DataSource = source;
        gv.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `ShowNoResultFound` after checking the length of  `gvNavigationDtls`. Try this

```
if(gvNavigationDtls.Rows.Count == 0)
{
  // show the footer
}
```

Comment: check your data count from result of query.. what you getting in your dataset or datatable?